# How to multiply python string and integer arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have two different lists which I would like to combine

a = ['A', 'B', 'C']

b = [2, 10, 120]

So the desired output should be like this:

ab = ['A2', 'B10', 'C120']

I've tried this:

ab = [a[i]*b[i] for i in range(len(a))]

But I now understand that this will only work if I want to multiply two array of integers. So what should I do in order to get the desired output as above?

Thank you.

Comment: what is `A`, `B`, and `C`? Are they supposed to be `a = ['A','B','C']` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for observing that. I've made edits to reflect that.

Comment: Your question is still very vague. `ab` is then `["A2","B10","C120"]` or `["AA", "BBBBBBBBB", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"]` ?

Comment: or maybe `0xa2, 0xb10, 0xc120` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zip()` to do this:

```
>>> zip(a, [str(i) for i in b])
[('A', '2'), ('B', '10'), ('C', '120')]
```

As such:

```
>>> a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> 
>>> b = [2, 10, 120]
>>> [y + z for (y, z) in zip(a, [str(i) for i in b])]
['A2', 'B10', 'C120']
>>>
```

In this example, we are first converting each integer in `b` to a string, so that we can do string concatenation, then we `zip` a and `b` together, so that we can easily loop over the new list using another list comprehension and string concatenation to get the desired result.

Comment: This code has a typo, and also won't work in 2.7, should be `[y+z for (y, z) in zip(a, [str(i) for i in b])]`

Comment: @qwwqwwq You are correct regarding the typo. Other than that, it works perfectly fine :)

Comment: @Sri, if this solved your question, could you accept it and +1 it? This gives **you** *+2* reputation!

Comment: @Sri I think edit was added to make the tuple after the `for` explicit, you need to do this in 2.7, thats what I was referring to.

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick You need to add the strings (y + z for (y,z)). Please edit and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 4):

The same idea as **To Click's**, but a little different, you can type cast after unpacking the items

```
>>> [str(y)+str(x) for y,x in zip(a, b)]
['A2', 'B10', 'C120']
```

Answer (score 1):

Although zip() is the preferred solution, I believe the original problems with the way you were doing it were:

1. You were not converting the integers to strings (solved in To Click's answer)
2. You were not adding the strings (still incorrect in To Click's answer)

There could be a problem if the arrays are of different sizes, a problem taken care of by zip().

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply a `string` and `int` values. You have to convert both into string format and then `concatenate`it. I executed the following code which actually outputs as you asked for.Hope it helps. Not surely the best way but definitely one of the ways to do it.

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']

b = [2, 10, 120]
ab=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    ab.append(a[i]+str(b[i]))
print ab
```

this is the output :

```
['A2', 'B10', 'C120']
```

Comment: well you can multiply, the result is not what OP expects though, `"a" * 5 == "aaaaa"`

Comment: @qarma OP expects `['A2', 'B10', 'C120']` right ? I think he has clearly mentioned that output should be of the type `ab = [A2, B10, C120]`. You mean to say no single quotes for each element in the list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
["".join(x) for x in zip(a, map(str, b))]
['A2', 'B50', 'C99']
```

or perhaps simpler:

```
["%s%s" % x for x in zip(a, b)]
```

assumin that OP had mising quotes in desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
[elem+a[count] for count,elem in enumerate(b)]
```

Try this with enumerate